# Is there any way to skip Odata metadata validation when using FluentHelperRead/Count with filters?

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I'm using sap-cloud-sdk for java to get(using also filters) SAP C4C Tickets.
My requests fail to execute due to metadata validation failure (see below stacktrace). Since this metadata is beyond my control and I'm not even interested in all the data I would prefer to have the option of skipping the validation (similar to the option of caching the metadata). Is there any way I can do it?

````
   2020-09-23T22:26:01.97+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at org.apache.olingo.odata2.client.core.ep.deserializer.XmlMetadataDeserializer.validateRelationship(XmlMetadataDeserializer.java:1483) ~[odata-v2-lib-1.39.0.jar:na]
   2020-09-23T22:26:01.97+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at org.apache.olingo.odata2.client.core.ep.deserializer.XmlMetadataDeserializer.validate(XmlMetadataDeserializer.java:1576) ~[odata-v2-lib-1.39.0.jar:na]
   2020-09-23T22:26:01.97+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at org.apache.olingo.odata2.client.core.ep.deserializer.XmlMetadataDeserializer.readMetadata(XmlMetadataDeserializer.java:181) ~[odata-v2-lib-1.39.0.jar:na]
   2020-09-23T22:26:01.97+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at org.apache.olingo.odata2.client.core.ODataClientImpl.readMetadata(ODataClientImpl.java:100) ~[odata-v2-lib-1.39.0.jar:na]
   2020-09-23T22:26:01.97+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.cache.metadata.GuavaMetadataCache.getEdm(GuavaMetadataCache.java:139) ~[odatav2-connectivity-sdk3-1.39.0.jar:na]
   2020-09-23T22:26:01.97+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.loadMetadata(ODataQuery.java:480) [odatav2-connectivity-sdk3-1.39.0.jar:na]
   2020-09-23T22:26:01.97+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.loadEntriesFromDestination(ODataQuery.java:326) [odatav2-connectivity-sdk3-1.39.0.jar:na]
   2020-09-23T22:26:01.97+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.internalExecute(ODataQuery.java:265) [odatav2-connectivity-sdk3-1.39.0.jar:na]
   2020-09-23T22:26:01.97+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.execute(ODataQuery.java:162) [odatav2-connectivity-sdk3-1.39.0.jar:na]
   2020-09-23T22:26:01.97+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.execute(ODataQuery.java:146) [odatav2-connectivity-sdk3-1.39.0.jar:na]
   2020-09-23T22:26:01.97+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.helper.FluentHelperCount.execute(FluentHelperCount.java:45) [odata-core-3.22.0.jar:na]
   2020-09-23T22:26:01.97+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at com.sap.chatbot.service.core.DefaultTicketService.getTotalNumberOfTickets(DefaultTicketService.java:222) [classes/:na]```

Thank you
````

Comment: Hi Sorina, C4C is known to interpret the OData standard a bit frivolously. Also, from the first glance, the exception happens in the code of one of the dependencies of the SDK. To let us have a closer look, can you also post your code snippet and update to the latest SDK version: https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/release-notes-sap-cloud-sdk-for-java

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace I can derive that you use SAP Cloud SDK 3.22.0 and you've generated your custom VDM for the C4C OData API. Let me recommend you to always stay up-to-date with the latest Cloud SDK version. Refer to our [release notes](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/release-notes-sap-cloud-sdk-for-java) for further reference.

Why exactly the metadata validation fails is impossible to say based on the provided information. However, as you pointed out, the solution might be to prevent the metadata access at all.

I recommend trying out the improved OData client of the SAP Cloud SDk. This new OData client library **does no longer lead to metadata access**. [Here](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/odata/use-typed-odata-v2-client-in-sap-cloud-sdk-for-java/#switch-to-improved-odata-v2-type-safe-client) is how to adjust your code base to leverage that new OData client.

Answer (score 0):

Sorina

Luckily today we're releasing a new version of improved OData v2 client which should solve metadata problem as it doesn't rely on dependencies used for previous client version. I can already see it uploaded to [mvn central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.sap.cloud.sdk/sdk-bom/3.29.1/pom)

Please, check our [documentation](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/odata/use-typed-odata-v2-client-in-sap-cloud-sdk-for-java/#switch-to-improved-odata-v2-type-safe-client) to easily migrate.

I hope if will solve you issue. In case not reach out to us again for a quick help.